# Unable to get :after to display inline with menu item text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to simply use the pseudo selector :after to add a > drop-down indicator inline next to the top level menu items.

Here's a JSFiddle showing two examples, the upper not working example, and a stripped down version how it should be working below: https://jsfiddle.net/z2rwe3wh/3/

The HTML is a bit of a mess, it's generated from a custom walker class in WordPress and each sub-menu has custom nested layouts and styles within the project - but, there's something in my CSS which is preventing the :after pseudo selector from behaving correctly and keeping the > marker inline to the right of the text.

Here's the pseudo selector being used for adding the markers to both menus (found in the CSS at the bottom of the JSFiddle).

```
nav ul li.master > a:after {
  content: " >";
  width: 10px;
  height: 5px;
}
```

If you don't mind a Sherlock Holmes moment, it would be much appreciated - I haven't been able to track it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because there is a div in the `<a>` tag. Divs are `display: block;` by default so this is pushing your `:after` element onto the next line.

Add the following to your css: `.name { display: inline; }`

In the working example, the `:after` and the text (not a div) are both within the `<a>` therefore sitting on the same line.

Comment: Laura, thank you, that worked perfectly ( and, you answered the question 3 min before it's letting me accept the answer :)

Comment: Awesome! Haha if you could tick it when it lets you that would be great :)